# Media query working for only 60px

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query that puts a margin under a div at a minimum width of `1200px`, and it works from 1200-1260px, but then reverts right back to no margin underneath after 1260px. This media query is the last media query in the stylesheet and there are no other `min-width 1200px` or `min-width` `media queries` in the whole style sheet. Is it something with my media query?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.padd-top {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
}
```

I have also tried `@media all` and `@media screen`

Comment: works fine for me... maybe show us some more of your code, html including

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.padd-top {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
}
```